# How to concurrently write a stream and read the data in node.js?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, stream

I have a node.js stream that I am temporarily writing to an array like this:

```
var tempCrossSection = [];

stream.on('data', function(data) {
    tempCrossSection.push(data);
});
```

Then I am periodically taking the data in that array (and clearing it) and doing some processing on it like this:

```
var crossSection = [];

setInterval(function() {
    crossSection = tempCrossSection;
    tempCrossSection = [];

    someOtherFunction(crossSection, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}, 30000);
```

The problem is that I get some odd behavior with the order that the stream is being written to the array and the number of setInterval callbacks that are fired as the stream rate increases and/or the someOtherFunction callback takes too long.

How should I implement this so that the stream is correctly writing data to the array (in order) and the data processing is being conducted once per setInterval callback.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The order will always be the same as the order of data from stream, you are just pushing into the array. How is that code called? The error seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Two things you can do: use setTimeout in the someOtherFunction callback instead of setInterval, and `crossSection = tempCrossSection.splice(0)` makes more sense for clearing the array. Not sure if those have anything to do with your problem though.

Comment: @freakish I have the same expectation, but in certain cases I have had console statements reflect varying (not sequentially larger) array.length(s)

Comment: @kas673 Well, this is a bit different. Something is removing these items from your array, but it's hard to believe that the order is actually messed up. Is it possible that more then one stream can push into that array at the same time?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the tips...I have used a recursive setTimeout with some improvement, but have still seen issues where the setTimeout callbacks deviate too far from "schedule" to be effective.

Comment: @freakish I will investigate the stream some more. In this case I am using the ntwitter module and the Twitter Streaming API so there could be some odd behavior related to that. The stream is not being initiated more than once though.

Comment: @kas673 I am not familiar with any API for Twitter in NodeJS, so I guess that I can only wish you good luck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. First of all you are sharing to much state.
For example crossSection should be solely defined in the anonymous Interval function.
Why is "crossSection" defined as a closure? If someOtherFunction runs for a long period you might indeed into somekind of race conditions.

```
var source = [];

stream.on('data', function(data) {
    source.push(data);
});

setInterval(function() {
    var target = source;
    source = [];

    someOtherFunction(target, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}, 30000);
```

If you have access to **someOtherFunction** then I would rewrite the whole thing like this

```
var source = [];

stream.on('data', function(data) {
    source.push(data);
});

setInterval(function() {
    var processing = true;

    while (processing) {
        var elem = source.shift();
        someOtherFunction(elem, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        processing = checkForBreakConditionAndReturnFalseIfBreak();
    }
}, 30000);
```

Still you might run into some issues if the number of elements is to big and **someOtherFunctions** takes to long. So I'd probably do something like this

```
var source = [];
var timerId = 0;

stream.on('data', function(data) {
    source.push(data);
});

function processSource() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    var processing = true;

    while (processing) {
        var elem = source.shift();
        someOtherFunction(elem, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        processing = checkForBreakConditionAndReturnFalseIfBreak();
    }
    setTimeout(processSource, calcTimeoutForNextProcessingDependentOnPastData());
};

setTimeout(processSource, 30000); //initial Timeout
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips there is some good stuff in there. I had some issues with express initiating subsequent streams which was the root of my problem.